# Why won't my system acknowledge a new path environment variable?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am using the GUI method (rather than setx) to set a directory in the %PATH% environment variable on windows 7. My aim is to enable all my python scripts, modules and classes that I place in my 'D:\MPhil\Python\My_Python_Modules' directory to be available to use in the command line or another python script, but from any directory (much like the native python modules can be called from anywhere).

I have been through the process of:
'Edit the system environment variables->Environment variables->add my directory to the start of the %PATH% variable'

such that it now looks like this

```
'D:\MPhil\Python\My_Python_Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo IDE 8\;...'
```

However, the 'Identify_Gene.py' script contained within the directory is still not callable (using the command 'python Identify_Gene.py', from a random directory.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a confusion between the `PATH` environment variable, which is where the shell (`cmd.exe`) searches for commands and the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable which initializes the `sys.path` variable that Python uses to find modules.

You can try 2 ways of doing (more or less) what you want :

- Windows normaly knows that `.py` and `.pyw` files must be executed through the `Python` interpreter. You can prepend the directory where you put your script to the `PATH` (like you did) and call your script **directly** (and not `python Identify_Gene.py`)

```
    Identify_Gene.py
```

- put only the directory containing python in the `PATH` and put the directory containing your scripts into `PYTHONPATH` (you can create new environment variables under Windows if it does not exists). You can the call your scripts as modules :

```
    python -m Identify_Gene
```

Comment: Okay, so I have removed the directory from %PATH% and created a new variable called PYTHONPATH. PYTHONPATH now contained my directory (D:\MPhil\Python\My_Python_Modules) which contains a single file called Identify_Gene.py, however I cannot invoke the script with the call python -m Identify_Gene.py. Is there something else I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Turns out that it worked and  my only problem was that I needed to restart the command line. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Add to Windows environment varibale `PATHEXT` python script extension:`.PY`

   `set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.PY`

   (use Env. Settings GUI to make it permament)
2. In command line: register that python extension:

   `assoc .py=Python.File`
3. In command line: add application invoker to the extension:

   `ftype Python.File=<path to python exe>\pythonw.exe "%%1" %%*`

Next time you could simply run your script by name in the command line and without `.py` extension (if you set your `PATH` variable).

Another option: you should add path of your scripts folder to the `PYTHONPATH` variable and then you could invoke your scripts in the form:

```
python -m <script name>
```

Comment: I have followed your instructions but I cannot see whether it worked or not as my main problem is setting the PATH variable.

Comment: I updated 3rd statement where you need specify path to python interperter, should work

Comment: It seems that I have successfully added the directory to the path but it still doesn't work. Can I ask a few questions: 

1) Do I add the directory to the entire folder or just the file I want to be able to call?

2) To call the script from anywhere, do I simply use the usual 'python hello_world.py' command or is there something else I have to do?

Comment: So, to call your script from anywhere you need add your folder with scripts into the `PYTHONPATH` variable and use `python -m <script name>`. If you'd like to use `PATH` variable and without extension and `python -m` command, then you need to go through the first solution (three steps to establish python scripts association in Windows)